# Was there a reason given for Crenshinibon (the Crystal Shard) to not be carried in the casket?

Tags: forgotten-realms, legend-of-drizzt

I read quite a few of the Drizzt books years ago, and am recently listening to them on Audiobooks.

I just finished *Passage to Dawn* and am about halfway through *Silent Blade*.

> In *Passage to Dawn* Regis defeated Crenshinibon by closing it into the small chest that had previously held the antimagic sapphire.  This chest had previously completely blocked the effects of the sapphire while closed, and assumedly did the same to the Shard.

> In *Silent Blade*, I first assumed that the small chest was in someone's (probably Drizzt's) backpack, as there seemed to be no other convenient way to carry it.  However, the description when they confront the first giant following them makes it seem as if Drizzt is just carrying the artifact loose in his pouch, with no mention of the chest.

**Did I miss a reason given that they are not using the chest to keep Crenshinibon contained?**

As a related bit of trivia that *might* relate to my question, I thought *Passage to Dawn* had a description of Crenshinibon that gave it a length of a foot.  I had thought it smaller, and had also thought the sapphire's chest too small to contain a foot long object.  Did I mishear that description?